# React integration with Stripe customer portal

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to get an integration with the stripe customer portal working in my react app so that when the user clicks a button it opens the customer portal and they are able to manage their subscriptions.

Currently I have the following set up to achieve this:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')("pk_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");



  const [session, setSession] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('loading in stripe')
    const doIt = async () => {
      const session = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
        customer: stripeId,
    
      });
      console.log("session is ", session)
      setSession(session);
    };
    doIt();
  }, []);
```

And the button to open the portal is as follows:

```
return (

  <>
      {session && session.url &&
      <form method="POST" action={session.url}>
        <button type="submit" className="Button">
          Membership
        </button>
      </form>}

  </>

);
```

The issue I am having is that the button doesn't show on the page so I am unable to click it to go to the customer portal.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to your conditional failing. Can you log your `session` object and see if it indeed has the values that you're looking for?

Comment: It doesn't have the value I am looking for, it returns 'undefined'. I'm very new to react, would there be a way you would suggest solving that?

Comment: Right, so you'd want to make sure that your code only tries to render the button if the session isn't undefined. 
Also, check if this returns an error of some kind.

```await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
        customer: stripeId,
      });```